# Normalize a given random value to the range of 0 - 1 in java

Tags: java, java-8, range, scaling, normalize

Say i get a value that is a difference of current time in milliseconds - some datetime in milliseconds.

```
double value = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - getMilliseconds(reportingDt);
```

So this would be a quite a big value. Now i want to normalize it to a scale of 0 - 1.

Please can some one suggest how can this be achieved in java, so that my value is scaled in between 0 and 1.

The more recent is the reportingDt more the final value is towards 1 and older the reportingDt more it is towards 0.

**UPDATE**

Well my approach towards normalizing it was as below. This is more of a prototype, but it worked for me.

```
private double getDocumentScore(String reportingDt) {

        Date offset = null;
        try {
            offset = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("24-08-2017 13:53:30.802");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); 
        if(offset != null) {
            // If offset is set then instead of current datetime consider offset
            currentTime = offset.getTime();
        }
        System.out.println(reportingDt);
        long value = currentTime - getMilliseconds(reportingDt);

        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(value);
        double score = 2 * (1 / Math.log(minutes));
        System.out.println(score);
        return score;
    }

    private long getMilliseconds(String dateTime) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dateTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date.getTime();
    }
```

Sample input date and output normalized score values were

```
11-07-2017 14:34:05.416
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:06.023
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:06.595
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:07.139
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:08.873
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:11.171
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:12.954
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:12.962
0.18089822028334113
11-07-2017 14:34:34.516
0.18089847869291217
11-07-2017 14:34:35.720
0.18089847869291217
11-07-2017 14:34:38.566
0.18089847869291217
11-07-2017 14:34:39.205
0.18089847869291217
11-07-2017 14:34:40.357
0.18089847869291217
```

Below is the graph plot for various score function i considered to normalize the value. Finally i used green line one (2* (1/log(x)))

[image]

Comment: What would be the range of that double value? You might want to think about that first because without a defined range you cannot normalize.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS i can get all the values, put it in a list and then find min and max value, thus have a range.

Comment: You can do it other way around, more recent `reportingDt` near to 0 and older toward 1. You can do it by dividing final value by`Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: @a_a no the other way would not get me the right thing i am looking for. It has to be more recent towards 1 and less recent towards 0.

Comment: @a_a  Also just dividing it won't restrict the answer to be in the range of 0 to 1.

Comment: Again: if you dont know **anything** about that `double value` - then you can't normalize it. Assume that value is 5000 on the first call. Should it be closer to 0 or to 1? What if the first value is 50000? You cant normalize without knowing anything about the range of the values you want to normalize!

Comment: @RahulLao try it, it will be in the range of 0 to 1. if you will divide value by `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`

Answer (score 3):

You said you can put all the values in a list and calculate the minimum and maximum values. Then each value can be normalized like this:

```
/**
 * Calculates a value between 0 and 1, given the precondition that value
 * is between min and max. 0 means value = max, and 1 means value = min.
 */
double normalize(double value, double min, double max) {
    return 1 - ((value - min) / (max - min));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that's impossible to solve. Why? Because time moves on and you would get different values for the very same DateTime value, depending on whether you execute your code today, tomorrow, in a year from now ...

You would have to have a fixed time range that you want to observe. If you say you wanna go from Jan 1st 1970 to Jan 1st 2070 you could simply divide your timespan's value by this maximum timespan value. Subtract 1 from it and set the result absolute. But this result will approach 1 only in the 60ies of this century. It is not really what you were asking for.

Then, on the other side, what's the use of having a floating point number with lots of digits behind the comma as opposed to a long value with lots of digits in front of the comma?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this-

```
double currenttime=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();    
double value= currenttime- getMilliseconds(reportingDt);
double normalized=(1- value/currenttime;
System.out.println(normalized);
```

Comment: This is equal to `getMilliseconds(reportingDt)/currenttime`. It will vary from negative numbers (for reportingDt earlier than 1970) to 1 (for reportingDt = now).